# QBO API V3.0: Persistent error today retrieving Tax Rates

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have consistently getting the following error today when using API V3.0 to retrieve TaxRate from QBO:

An application error has occurred while processing your request - Detail: System Failure Error: An unexpected error occurred while accessing or saving your data. Please wait a few minutes and try again.  If the problem persists, contact customer support. - Error Code: 10000

Is this a temporary issue with the servers or has something changed in the API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the taxrate endpoints(findById and Query) from ApiExplorer and got a successful response.

```
GetById - https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/688779980/taxrate/2

Query - https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/688779980/query?query=select * from TaxRate
```

[image]

Can you please give it a try from ApiExplorer and check if you are hitting the correct endpoints. Otherwise you can raise a support ticket mentioning your company's relamID.

**EDIT**
Standard BASE URL for V3 - https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company

We get the following when we try this call using devkit -

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1119166485/query?query=select+*+from+TaxRate&requestid=faf9f5e207134f24930eef40c9b8a21a&
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response Manas. It works for me using the ApiExplorer for the same realmID. I will look into it some more why it does not work from our code as this is something it has been working for a few months now.

Comment: I noticed that the APIExplorer uses https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3 wheres we are using https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3 which is the documented one. We should keep using the latter, right ?

Comment: Manas, actually the query fails also in the APIExplorer. I tried before the simple select and it works, but the query that is failing is the count query. I here below adding a screenshoot of it

Comment: Here is the query that fails also with the ApiExplorer and the response:

https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/1063929550/query?query=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TaxRate

    <Error code="10000">
      <Message>An application error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
      <Detail>System Failure Error: An unexpected error occurred while accessing or saving your data. Please wait a few minutes and try again.  If the problem persists, contact customer support.</Detail>

Comment: If the problem persists then please raise a suppport ticket mentioning  request/response XML and your company's relamID. Are you trying these calls using IPP's devkit ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in .net devkit where IDSquery will not work for count.
You need to use the following lamda function until the fix is in place-

QueryService AccQueryService2 = new QueryService(context);

int accs22= AccQueryService2.Select(c => c).Count();

Refer:
https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/829658-how-to-select-count-from-invoice-using-idsquery-to-return-int?jump_to=comment_1941998

EDIT:

The team has identified this a bug. They will rectify this in the next release around 1 month from now.

Comment: Thanks Nimisha. We are not using .net devkit. We have already raised a ticket as we get the same error with the ApiExplorer for this realmId. The thing is that this has been working for the last few months. So something must have changed in the back end.